# How to start an activity with a custom layout from Wearable when Handheld device receives a Push Notification

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client, android-intentservice, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to launch an Activity form a Wearable device (watch) when a push notification is received on a handheld device.

I read in other questions that I will need to send data over to Wearable, then in the "onDataChanged" event I can build the notification from the wearable device and add a PendingIntent with the desired wearable activity. But in order to do that I will have to initialize and connect a GoogleAPIClient from the intent service on the handheld device that received the push nitification which is the part that I am kind of struggling with. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To Trigger when PUSH notification received, u need to inherit `BroadcastReceiver`and/or [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) & in that use `onReceive()` method to send data to wear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am trying to connect the ApiClient from a service that does not run on the UI thread I was able to do that

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
 mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for help getting started with the GoogleAPIClient, [this](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing.html) may help.

Comment: Thanks @eshayne for your help. I have looked at that link before I ask this question. I think I made it work and I will post the answer shortly.